# Routing Problem

Tags: routing, ubiquiti

I have an Ubiquiti Edgerouter X that is receiving the internet over PPPoe from a Modem.

The router is configured to have network 192.168.1.0/24 and provide DHCP to devices.

Plugged into one of the ports on the router is a Tenda MW6 Nova Mesh device, which is picking up a DHCP address from the router.  Its then providing 192.168.5.0/24 to the wifi devices, itself being 192.168.5.1 on that network and 192.168.1.184 on the wired network.

Devices on the wifi network can see the internet and access devices on the wired network.  However devices on the wired network can not access devices on the wifi network.  This is by ping, traceroute or ssh.

Now I logged onto the router and tried to add a static route to 192.168.5.0/24 with the next hop being 192.168.1.184 that doesn't seem to have worked.

So I wonder if anyone could help point me in the right direction.

If this is the wrong forum I'm sorry.

[image: Network Diagram Basic]

[image: Route Config]

Now I assume

Comment: Unfortunately, questions bout consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su] .